# i was supposed to print 5,4,3,2,1 as per the problem statement,but my c++ code is showing some error

Tags: function, recursion, c++14

ERROR i'm getting

> F:\coding\code blocks\hello.cpp|14|error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'void')|

my code

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    void fun(int n)
    {

        if (n==0) return;
        cout<<n<<endl;
        fun(n-1);
    }
    int main()
    {

        cout << fun(5)<< endl;

    }
```

Comment: This is a problem: `cout << fun(5)<< endl;`.  `fun` `return`s `void` (AKA nothing).

Comment: `cout << (void) <<endl;` looks strange, right?

Comment: `fun(5);` is enough. remove `cout` in main function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two issues:

1. `fun`´s return type is `void`. Thus, this:

```
cout << fun(5) << endl;
```

can´t work as expected. To use the value of a `void` returning function invokes undefined behavior.

2. The printing in `main` of `n` in general is redundant as you already print it in `fun()`.

---

Rather do it like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) 
       return;

    cout << n << endl;

    fun(n - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    fun(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

int the main function .
instead of writing

```
cout<<fun(5)<<endl;
```

write like this.

fun(5);

Answer (score 0):

Your function `fun` returns `void`, also there is no need to use `cout` twice, use it either in `main` or in the function body `fun`. Try this code to get the output "as per your problem statement":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int n)
{
    if (n==0) 
       return 0;
    ((n-1)==0)?(cout<<n<<endl):(cout<<n<<",");
    fun(n-1);
}
int main()
{
    fun(5);
    return 0;
}
```